# Where is sublime.py?

Tags: python, plugins, text-editor, sublimetext

Sublime Text2 text editor is extended via python scripts, using these modules:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
```

I've searched my computer and found `sublime_plugin.py` file.
But where is `sublime.py`?

Comment: underneath the lime pie ?  Sorry :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that Sublime is provided dynamically when you call the plugin via the console.

Remember that an import doesn't have to be a physical .py file, it can be a library or an in-memory representation.

I found a decent reference to the confusions often related to Import, it's a little old now but I believe it's still relevant:

http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Edit:  Just to confirm that, I've checked and the Python2.6 runtime is embedded inside the executable for Sublime, and the Sublime module is defined inside there.